# capi engine: function not supported

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, curl, openssl

I tried to resolve issue but not getting any solution everytime getting below error.

OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0

OS version : - 22.04.2 LTS
openssl version : - OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023

I tried to sign a binary from windows client but getting error capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported